# Alinhamento checkbox em select optgroup

Tags: html, jquery, css

Como faço para alinhar como na imagem abaixo os checkbox e o label?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui não está carretando direito, para melhor visualização pode acessar:

### http://jsfiddle.net/8f7aLch6/

Código:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#chkveg').multiselect({

   includeSelectAllOption: true;

  });

});
```

```css
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 50px 3px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css">


<form id="form1">

  <div style="padding:20px">

    <select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
      <optgroup label="Frist Queue" id="Frist Queue">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
      </optgroup>

      <optgroup label="Second Queue" id="Second Queue">
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Cara não entendi direito, vc quer primeiro o Texto e depois o checkbox? Não entendi exatamente como vc quer alinhar as coisas....

Comment: O `label` posicionado a esquerda e os `checkbox` mais posicionado a direita. Somente para destacar mais os grupos.

Comment: Gostaria que ficasse assim https://prnt.sc/p9ukig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que estilizar fazendo um Override do CSS do componente do MultiSelect que vc usou

Usando esse CSS, repare que eu usei um `a:not(.multiselect-all)` para não pegar o `padding` no `checkbox` "select all"

```
.multiselect-container>li>a:not(.multiselect-all)>label.checkbox {
  padding-left: 40px !important;
}
```

E para ajustar o label do optiongroup vc usa esse CSS

```
.multiselect-item.multiselect-group a label b {
  margin-left: -20px
}
```

Vc consegue esse resultado: **Veja no link** http://jsfiddle.net/uo8v45qj/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Frist e o Second, deveria ficar no mesmo alinhamento do Select all.

Comment: @Tiago a sim entendi, veja o EDIT que fiz na resposta, atualizei o link, a imagem e inclui um CSS a mais que vc vai precisar. Veja se ficou como imaginava

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @Tiago Sem problemas meu caro

Answer (score 0):

retira o label

```
.multiselect-container>li>a{
    padding: 4px 50px 3px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Se eu retiro fica assim https://prnt.sc/p9ue81, o label tem que ficar mais para a direita.

Comment: Gostaria que ficasse assim https://prnt.sc/p9ukig